# phpmailer not showing images in html

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connections/db.php";
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$Email = $_POST['email1'];
$link = $_POST['link1'];
include "SMTP.php";
require 'phpmailer/vendor/autoload.php';
include 'PHPMailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '********@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'owais@1';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->setFrom('inboxowaislatif@gmail.com', 'Cloud Asset, Oy');
$mail->addAddress($Email, 'Cloud Asset, Oy');
$mail->Subject = 'Download pdf';
$mail->Body =
    '
<style>
body
{
background-color:blue;
}
</style>
<body style="background-image: url(http://88.194.145.207:8882/p3-fi/bgimage.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-position: center; background-size: cover;">
<div style="height:70px;"></div>
<div style="background-image: url(http://88.194.145.207:8882/p3-fi/bgimage.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-position: center; background-size: cover;"></div>
<div style="
    display: flex;
    /* Or whatever */

">
    <img src="http://88.194.145.207:8882/p3-fi/logo.png" style="

    margin: auto;
    "/>
</div>
<div style="height:30px; "></div>
<div style="width:50%; height:200px; display:flex; margin:auto; background-image: url(http://88.194.145.207:8882/p3-fi/image2.jpg);  background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-position: center; background-size: cover;">

<a href="http://88.194.145.207:8882/p3-fi/' .
    $link .
    '" style="text-align:center; margin:auto;"><img src="http://88.194.145.207:8882/p3-fi/download.png" style="margin:auto; border-radius:100px; cursor:pointer;" /></a><br><br>

</div>
<div style="width:50%; height:50px; margin:auto; background-image: url(http://88.194.145.207:8882/p3-fi/image2.jpg);  background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-position: center; background-size: cover;">
 <h3 style="color:white; text-align:center; margin:0px;"><a href="http://88.194.145.207:8882/p3-fi/' .
    $link .
    '" style="color:white; text-decoration:none;">DOWNLOAD FILE<a/></h3>
</div>
<div style="width:50%; margin:auto; background-color:white;">

  <h3 style="margin:0px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-top:30px; Text-align:center;">P3 SME digital POS for banks,<br>Ready To download</h3>
  <p style="padding:20px; text-align:center; margin:0px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In congue arcu a posuere mattis. Integer mollis eleifend lorem id sodales. Duis sollicitudin diam enim,</p>


</div>
<div style="width:50%; margin:auto; position:relative; text-align:center; background-color:white; height:100px; ">
  <button style="background-color:#2C15D9; margin-top:25px;  color:white; border-color:blue; border-radius:100px; width:150px; height:30px;"><b>GET NOW</b></button>
</div>
<div style="width:50%; margin:auto; background-color:white; display:flex;">
<table align="center" style="">
    <tr style="margin:0px;">
     <td style="padding:10px;"><img src="http://88.194.145.207:8882/p3-fi/facebook.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;"/></td>
         <td style="padding:10px;"><img src="http://88.194.145.207:8882/p3-fi/twitter.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;"/></td>
         <td style="padding:10px;"><img src="http://88.194.145.207:8882/p3-fi/instagram.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;"/></td>
         <td style="padding:10px;"><img src="http://88.194.145.207:8882/p3-fi/youtube.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;"/></td>
             <td style="padding:10px;"><img src="http://88.194.145.207:8882/p3-fi/google.png" style="width:20px; height:20px;"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>  
<div style="width:50%; margin:auto; background-color:white; height:50px;">&nbsp;</div>    
<div style="height:30px;"></div>
<p style="text-align:center; color:white;">@2018 P3 by CloudAssest&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" style="color:white;"><u>Unsubscribe</u></a><p>
</body>

';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
//$mail->AddAttachment($link);
if ($mail->send()) {
    $query = "insert into users (user_email,date,download_pdf) values ('$Email','$date','$link')";
    $run = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    if ($run) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $Email;
        echo "Email send successfully";
    }
}
?>
```

Hello Every one,
  I am using php mailer for sending emails with a template. It is working perfectly with using gmail but when i tested it in outlook no images are being show the code above is working perfectly with gmail.

The image below is for gmail:

[image]

This image is for outlook:

[image]

Comment: Outlook doesn't support `background-image` property, use [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background-image/) as reference for a list of supported styles. [This one](http://freshinbox.com/blog/outlook-com-and-background-images/) is a possible workaround to get background-image working using the `background` attribute

Answer (score -1):

Outlook by default block the images.  You can check with outlook settings

Click the File > Options.
Click Trust Center.
Click the Trust Center Settings button.
Uncheck the box next to the "Don't download pictures automatically in HTML e-mail messages or RSS items" option.

Second work around is you can use

```
$mailer->AddEmbeddedImage
```